# Installing/booting Windows installation from GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot

I need access to Windows for school. I had an issue dual-booting with Windows 8 so now I only have Ubuntu. I made a Windows 7 USB installer but for some reason the BIOS won't recognize the USB.

I was hopping and wondering if there is a way to load an USB through grub?

Comment: Did you had any boot from usb option in bios?

Comment: yes/no, when the ubuntu usb stick is there it gives me the option, when there is the WIndows usb stick it wont recognize it

Comment: did you please upload your bios screenshot?

Comment: thanks guys, one of the main reasons for the swap to windows 8 was for the AMD card in it, I finally got it too work, still so I'll be sticking to a full ubuntu install, and virtual boxing windows 8 or 7 thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

have you check you boot settings in biso settings to load from usb first 
and usb devices enebled

then load

here is step by step

1) Change the BIOS boot order so the USB device option is listed first.

2) Attach the USB device to your computer via any available USB port.

3) Restart your computer.

4) Watch for a Press any key to boot from external device

i hope this was helpfull

if not please let me know i will help trobleshoot this problem :)

Comment: Ive tried that, no luck, my ubuntu usb install works but the windows install usb wont get detected

Comment: Have you checked the usb in other pc that it loads there if not let me know i will give you in detail how to burn a windows installation on a usb stick

Comment: i havent had a chance on tryin it on any other pc, I burnt ist using winusb, but if you know of another way Id love to give it a try.

Comment: Once i get home i will post how to burn windows on usb

Answer (score 0):

How to Burn Windows Image:

Step 1: Download 
[Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Step 2: Launch Program

Step 3: Inside Program Follow Steps (Make sure you use windows xp and above to burn iso image )

a) Choose the OS you want to install
b) Select the iso image of the Windows
c) Select the flash drive (Make sure its FAT32 formated)
d) Click Create and then wait till it says: Process Complete!

and now try loading windows usb stick.

let me know if you still getting problems